# Stilfrage zu Abkürzungen in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten

Tags: style, abbreviation, scientific-language

Angenommen ich führte eine Abkürzung zu einem Begriff ein, wie in diesem Beispiel "künstliche Intelligenz (KI)":

> Die künstliche Intelligenz (KI) spielt in diesem Bereich eine große Rolle. Arbeiten wie [1] setzen KI ein, um...

Wenn ich den Begriff dann einige Seiten nicht benutze, neige ich häufig dazu, den Begriff wieder auszuschreiben.
Einige Seiten weiter:

> In dieser Arbeit werden Verfahren der künstlichen Intelligenz eingesetzt, um...

Ist es ein schlechter Stil, wenn man den ausgeschriebenen Begriff wiederverwendet, nachdem man die Abkürzung bereits eingeführt hat?

Comment: Ich denke KI ist eine so weit bekannte Abkürzung, dass man sie ohne Probleme verwenden kann. Anders verhält es sich bei obskureren Abkürzungen.

Comment: Was "schlechter Stil" ist lässt sich mE schwer allgemein beantworten. Ich kann mir Situationen vorstellen wo ein späteres Aussschreiben des Begriffes sinnvoll sein kann, z.B. in längeren Arbeiten mit eigenständig stehenden Kapiteln. In vielen Fällen ist es aber vermutlich konsequenter eine einmal eingeführte Abkürzung auch konsistent zu verwenden. Das scheint auch hier und da explizite Vorgabe bei Studienarbeiten zu sein, siehe z.B. S. 20  hier: https://www.uni-trier.de/fileadmin/fb4/prof/BWL/APO/Homepage_Abschlussarbeiten/20171025_LeitfadenMOP.pdf

Comment: @AndreasM Bei der Vorgabe der Uni Trier wird die Abkürzung eingeführt mit „(im Folgenden: [Abkürzung])“. Würdest du da einen Unterschied sehen, wenn man das „im Folgenden“ nicht schreibt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, das ist schon ok so.

Guter Stil ist Abkürzungen genau so wie von dir beschrieben einzuführen. Das zwingt einen aber nicht, ab dann vollkommen auf die Langform zu verzichten. Gerade, wenn der Begriff längere Zeit nicht im Text vorkam, kann es die Lesbarkeit deutlich erhöhen, wenn man zwischendurch wieder mal die Langform verwendet und vielleicht sogar ein zweites Mal die Abkürzung einführt.

Dringend zu empfehlen ist auch ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis in dem alle im Dokument verwendeten Abkürzungen aufgelistet werden.

Aber noch sehr viel wichtiger ist es, sich peinlich genau an alle Vorgaben zu halten, die der Verlag oder das Institut vorgibt. Solche Verlagsregeln übertrumpfen immer alle anderen Regeln und Empfehlungen. Verstöße gegen solche verbindlichen Formvorgaben können schnell mal dazu führen, dass ein Paper abgewiesen wird. Meist darf man solche Fehler zwar korrigieren und eine überarbeitete Version einreichen, aber oft ist dann die Zeit knapp, und das verursacht nur unnötigen Stress.

Comment: Was ist der Zusmmenhang für den letzten Absatz?

Comment: @sermonionx: Die Regeln wissenschaftlicher Verlage können im Widerspruch zu den hier gegebenen Empfehlungen stehen. Daher hielt ich es für wichtig, darauf hinzuweisen, dass die Verlagsregeln immer Vorrang haben.